# Moment of Inertia of a Cylinder with Cavity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

Well, I have to calculate the moment of inertia of a cylinder that has radius $R_1$ and the cavity $R_2$.
I tried doing just as you calculate the moment of inertia of a solid cylinder but instead of integrating from $0$ to $R$ doing it from $R_2$ to $R_1$.
$$I = \int{r^2dm}$$
Density is $\rho=M/V$, considering a ring that has mass equal to $dm$, volume $dv=2\pi rhdr$, since $dm = \rho dv$ we can do
$$\int r^2 \rho dv = \frac{2M}{R^2}\int_{R2}^{R1} r^3 = \frac{2M}{R^2}(\frac{{R_1}^4-{R_2}^4}{4})$$
This is when I got stuck, could I say $R=R_1-R_2$ to simplify the equation? Is my idea right? If so how could I proceed to simplify even more?

Comment: can you explain your prefactor of $2M/R^2$? Maybe it would be a good idea to stick to just expressing everything with your constant $\rho$ in the equation ...

Comment: $\rho = M/V$, but what is $V$ for you case?

Comment: @QuantumBrick would be volume of the cylinder, when you get $\rho$ out of the integral for being a constant it becomes $M/V$ where $V=\pi R^2$ and as $dv=2\pi r dr$ you leave $r$ and $dr$ inside the integral, the rest is constant and you take it out, doind $\rho = 2M/R^2$

Comment: @Sanya is the comment above helpful?

Comment: I think you mean $V=\pi R^2 h$? But this is the volume of the complete cylinder, not a cylinder which is empty inside ... But yes, your explanation helps. I think your only "mistake" is to have expressed $\rho$ incorrectly. (In other words, there will not be much simplification possible in any case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake is when you computed the volume of the cylinder, it is $\pi (R_1^2-R_2^2)h$ and you seem to have used $\pi (R_2 -R1 )^2h$. Once you change that it is easy to simplify:

$\frac{R_1^4-R_2^4}{R_1^2-R_2^2}=R_2^2+R_1^2$ and you get the correct result